# Remove all records with duplicates in db2. (Not just the duplicate records)

Tags: db2, delete, duplication

How can I remove all the records with duplicates in db2. I have looked at various answers but they only remove the duplicates leaving one record from that set in the table. This is what I found already.

DELETE FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ONE, TWO, THREE) AS RN
     FROM SESSION.TEST) AS A
WHERE RN > 1;

But, I need a query that will remove all the records that contain duplicates not leaving behind one of them in the table.

A      A       1  <-- delete this
 A      A       2  <-- delete this too
 B      B       3
 C      C       4

P.S: Using RN >= 1 does not work as it will make the table empty by deleting all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your desired uniqueness constraint is `(one,two)`, here is one way to do it:

`DELETE FROM session.test WHERE (one, two) IN 
(
   SELECT one, two FROM session.test 
   GROUP BY one, two
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)`

Comment: Nice! I was stumped myself on trying to figure this one out. Having tested it, I can say it works.